# React using wrong IP address for localhost

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to run the most basic react app possible and run it locally. I have referred to the startup docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

I run the app using both `npm start` from the docs and `yarn start` as indicated in the terminal.  The result in the terminal looks like this:

[image]

My app appears to be running, but the IP address looks wrong. When I copy and paste this into my browser's address bar or try `localhost:3000`, my page does not load.

Other solutions I tried after referencing other StackOverflow threads:

- restarting my computer
- changing the port to another port
- deleting and rebuilding the node_modules folder with `yarn`

None of those worked. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the command `unset HOST` in the terminal just before starting up my app and this worked.

Also, several other threads have referenced this article: https://choy.medium.com/fixing-create-react-app-when-npm-fails-to-start-because-your-host-environment-variable-is-being-4c8a9fa0b461

To set your localhost in .bash_profile do the following in the terminal...

Open bash profile in nano
`nano .bash_profile`

type `HOST="localhost"` and save this file

back in the terminal, type
`source .bash_profile`